# Table Function R - how to remove rows with 0

Tags: r

When I perform the table function 
`table(Subset_Region_Data$Type)`

I get an output that looks like this:

```
Var1 Freq 
A1     10  
A2      3   
A3      0   
A4     13  
A5      0
```

I would like to know how to remove the variables with frequency = 0. In this case, I'd like to remove variables A3 and A5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to suppress printing of 0 lines of a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833676/how-to-suppress-printing-of-0-lines-of-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the unused levels using `droplevels`:

```
table(droplevels(Subset_Region_Data$Type))
```